# Continuing a Task<T> to a Task<U> without blocking on Result

Tags: .net, asynchronous

I have two asynchronous methods `Task<int> DoInt()` and `Task<string> DoString(int value)`.  I have a third asynchronous method `Task<string> DoBoth(int value)` whose goal is to asynchronously execute `DoInt()`, piping it's output to `DoString(int)` and having the result be the result of `DoBoth()`.

The important constraints are:

1. I may not have source code to `DoInt()` or `DoString()`, so I can't
   modify them.
2. I don't want to block at any point
3. Output (result) of one task must be passed as input to the next
4. The final output (result) is what I want to be the result of `DoBoth()`

The key being I already have methods that are asynchronous (i.e. return Task) and I want to pipe data from task to task, without blocking along the way, returning the final result in the initial task.  I can do all the following except not blocking in the following code:

Code example:

```
// Two asynchronous methods from another library, i.e. can't be changed
Task<int> DoInt(); 
Task<string> DoString(int value);

Task<string> DoBoth()
{
    return DoInt().ContinueWith<string>(intTask => 
    {
        // Don't want to block here on DoString().Result
        return DoString(intTask.Result).Result; 
    });
}
```

Since `Task<string> DoString(int)` is already an asynchronous method, how do I cleanly create a non-blocking continuation to it?  Effectively I want to create a continuation from an existing Task and not from a Func.

Comment: Does `DoInt` take an int as an argument, or not?  You have it both ways in your post...

Comment: @ReedCopsey - I fixed the signature for DoInt().  Whether it has a parameter or not isn't important in the example, but the inconsistency in my example is confusing :)  Also renamed valueTask => intTask for clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write the entire chain using [TaskExtensions.Unwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917.aspx) as:

```
Task<string> DoBoth(int value)
{
    Task<Task<string>> task = DoInt(value).ContinueWith(valueTask => 
    {
        return DoString(valueTask.Result); 
    });

    return task.Unwrap();
}
```

Note that this assumes that `DoInt` is defined as `Task<int> DoInt(int value);`, which differs from your description, but follows your code example.

If DoInt does not take an int argument (matching your declarations), this could become:

```
Task<string> DoBoth()
{
    return DoInt().ContinueWith(t => DoString(t.Result)).Unwrap();
}
```

---

As an extra - using C# 5 and .NET 4.5 (or the async targeting pack), you can write this as:

```
async Task<string> DoBoth(int value)
{
    int first = await DoInt(value);
    return await DoString(first);
}
```

Comment: `valueTask.Result` won't block but `DoString(valueTask.Result).Result` will block until the task returned by `DoString()` is completed.   And by blocking, I don't mean the original caller being blocked; I just mean a thread sitting there potentially idle waiting for another task to complete (in this case the thread is running an asynchronous delegate, but it's still a thread from a system resource perspective).

Comment: Great! Reed, if you could just clarify; will there be no blocking even though you take `valueTask.Result`?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson No - at the point where you grab result, you're in a continuation.  `valueTask` is guaranteed to be completed at that point, so `.Result` becomes non-blocking.  (It may still raise an exception, however, if the task was canceled or failed, but it will never block.)

Comment: @MikeJansen Using Unwrap() as I've shown avoids putting the second `.Result` in place, which is why this never blocks.  There is no wasted resources in the code as shown.

Comment: @MikeJansen Just a little FYI - I showed how you can write this using VS2012, as well...

Comment: @ReedCopsey - my first comment was to your original answer, which I think got replaced with the current answer :)  The current answer is exactly what I'm looking for -- a framework method of getting the result from a task in an task/asynchronous efficient manner.  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeJansen Yeah - I misunderstood what you were saying originally - I had already edited it by the time you commented, though, which is why I was confused ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like flatMap method in functional languages. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#fmap_and_join